# won't let me access json object, what im missing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

So I'm trying to access an array inside an object:

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {},
      isLoading: true
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://m0n5ter-crawler.herokuapp.com/api/articles/`, {
        method: "GET",
      })
      .then(res => res.json(res))
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: res._embedded.articles, //this is where im entering the array of objects
          isLoading: false
        })
      })
      .catch((err => {
        console.error(err);
      }));
  }

  render() {
    const {
      isLoading,
      data
    } = (this.state);
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

this is what i get in the console log:

```
(1000) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
[0 … 99]
0: {groups: Array(1), date: "2015-12-03", url: "https://www.scmagazine.com", title: "", _links: {…}}
1: {groups: Array(1), date: "2018-10-19", url: "https://www.scmagazine.com/", title: "", _links: {…}}
2: {groups: Array(1), date: "2018-06-26", url: "https://www.scmagazine.com", title: ""
[100 … 199]
[200 … 299]
[300 … 399]
[400 … 499]
[500 … 599]
[600 … 699]
[700 … 799]
[800 … 899]
[900 … 999]
length: 1000
__proto__: Array(0)
```

`map` isn't a function, and `forEach` is `undefined`,
I  was trying to do key value on it but the value returned me `[object object]` or `undefined`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Your code doesn't use `map` or `forEach`. You need to provide a [mcve] (and fix the whitespace in your code, it's really hard to read)

Comment: It's hard to help you without more information, but one thing that jumps out is that you seem to be expecting an array from the `fetch` call (`res._embedded.articles`) which you set as `data` in your state, but your initial state is `{}`, a non-array object. So at a minimum you should change your initial state for `data` to `[]` (an empty array). But again, it's hard to help beyond that, and I wouldn't expect you to be using `data` when `isLoading` is true anyway...

Comment: Side note: It's not the problem, but your code is prey to the [`fetch` footgun](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. You should check for HTTP success before calling `json()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initiate data as an object `{}` and the first render takes `data` from the initial state.

```
this.state = {
  data: {},
  isLoading: true
}
```

Change it to Array

```
this.state = {
  data: [],
  isLoading: true
}
```

Comment: I can argue with you about that :) https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-varahamihira-7kjdc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: how could i miss that?

Comment: I don't know.. I even don't know what you missed ;) Is it working now for you?

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck.